# How to use a constructer of java class into fragment?

Tags: android

[![enter image description here][1]][1]HI all I am having a problem can anyone tell me how do I resolve this , I want to use a constructer in fragment class:
here is my both classes 
AppLocationService:

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 2;

    public AppLocationService(Context context) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public Location getLocation(String provider) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                    MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                return location;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

here is fragment:

```
public class AddressFragment extends Fragment {
    Button ShowAddress;
    TextView tvAddress;

    AppLocationService appLocationService;
    public AddressFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, false);
        tvAddress = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.input_location);
        appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
                AddressFragment.this);


        ShowAddress = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_location);
        ShowAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Location location = appLocationService
                        .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                //you can hard-code the lat & long if you have issues with getting it
                //remove the below if-condition and use the following couple of lines
                //double latitude = 37.422005;
                //double longitude = -122.084095

                if (location != null) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LocationAddress locationAddress = new LocationAddress();
                    locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(latitude, longitude,
                            getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());
                } else {
                    showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }




    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AddressFragment.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("SETTINGS");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Enable Location Provider! Go to settings menu?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        AddressFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            String locationAddress;
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                    locationAddress = bundle.getString("address");
                    break;
                default:
                    locationAddress = null;
            }
            tvAddress.setText(locationAddress);
        }
    }




        // Inflate the layout for this fragment



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this in your fragment in onCreateView methord : 
appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
                getActivity());

Comment: set appLocationService = new AppLocationService( getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question; A `Fragment` does not derive from `Context`. To let your code compile, you should change this

```
appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
            AddressFragment.this);
```

To this

```
appLocationService = new AppLocationService(getActivity());
```

However, you should never call a constructor of a `Service` yourself. You should start it with `Context#startService(Intent)` (in your case `getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), AppLocationService.class))`. To supply any parameters for your service, take a look at `Intent#putExtra(String, String)`

Comment: hi I done I fix that one ,but now it show Error:(67, 29) error: cannot find symbol method getApplicationContext()

Comment: I didn't mention anything about `getApplicationContext()`. You're now making the same mistake as you did before. You can call `getApplicationContext()` from a context derived class, which (as I said) Fragment is not

Comment: do I replace getActivity with getApplicationContext()

Comment: Yes you replace with getApplicationContext() with getActivity().

Comment: To fix your build error, you would have to use `getActivity()` rather than `getApplicationContext()`. However, as I get the feeling that your not familiar with Services in Android, I would recommend reading https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE I fix that but when I press the button app gone close

Comment: Please update the question with the crash log or, even better, create a new question with your current problem